# Serialize SecuritToken to xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml, iis, serialization, token

we are working on***Web API application*** which uses ***security tokens*** for authentications, for some reasons we needed to put this tokens along with username into memory Cache. and on second request the token is already exist and there is no need to enter username and password. So everything is OK. but due to some policies, the ***IIS is restarted after 24 hours*** and the cache will be empty, so on, the token is disappeared and the users need to login again! I decided to save and ***serialize the tokens into a local file*** and retrieve when they are needed, after 24 hours! But the security token class is an abstract class and cannot be serialized to xml! I am ***overriding WriteToken()*** Method from ***securityTokenHandler*** to change the object into string! but it has some difficulties. some properties are hard to cast to string!

***Do you know how can I do this task?***

Is it the best solution ?

the only thing which comes to my mind now is that cast each property into the right type and then get the value into string!

Which properties sre most importatn, I guess ; Token Xml and Validdate! 
Thanks, please let me know if the problem is not much clear to explain better,

Comment: Why are you overriding the `WriteToken` method? Whatever concrete class you are using must already be providing an implementation. The very purpose of this method IS to serialize the token to a string.

Comment: Yes, because I need the token with it's exact values, I intend to serialize the token, save it in a file and then retrieve it, when  its needed. but it is somehow hard for me. do you have any sample code to serialize a token into a string?

Comment: I think you are having issues with the cookies.  You application (httprequest) is looking up the URL and automatically adding a cookie to the request.  The server is clearing the cookie when it reboots so it is not recognizing the cookies and not allowing you to login.  So one solution is to delete the cookie for every new request.  The other solution is to send the request and when it fail then delete the cookie.  So I expect that when you are successful the server send back a 200 done, and a failure it a different status.  The way of continuing is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.

Comment: I just need a simple example to serialize a token  into a string, I found something in MSDN but it is not clear enough!